# como quitarle el unique a un campo

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

me gustaría saber como quitarle el unique a un campo que está como llave primaria, he intentado quitandosela desde la interfaz, pero siempre me da este problema[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he quitado en todas las tablas los campos en los que hacía referencia y sigue dandome este problema(lo que quiero hacer es que el campo cod_cia puedan repetirse datos cod_cia=9 nombre=nemo, cod_cia=9 nombre=Romeo)tal como el ejemplo que acabo de poner

Comment: El error dice que no lo sacaste de todos lados.. igual, no entiendo porque querrias romper una tabla asi...

Comment: he logrado tener la referencia con otra parte, para que esa llave no de problemas, incluso el programa que hice, las une sin problema, entonces... como dije anteriormente, la he sacado de todas las tablas, para que no me diera ese problema, y me lo sigue mandando